# Report on Campaign to show Leads Converted and Opportunities Closed Last Quarter

Tags: leads, campaign, joined-reports, campaign-member

I need a report which shows Leads associated with in the last Quarter as well as the revenue the Campaign has generated in the last Quarter.  I have been able to build to separate reports - one report showing the Leads created in last quarter and associated with the Campaign and the other report showing the Opportunities Closed in last quarter. However, I have been unable to create a single report  or create a joined report combining them.

Is there a joined report possible here wherein I can combine the 2 reports based on Campaign Name?

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard report type available that should be what you are looking to see.

```
Campaigns with Leads and Converted Lead Information
```

[image: Campaigns with Leads and Converted Lead Information]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the help for "Joined Report" from the below links :

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_examples_joined.htm&language=en_US

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_working_with_joined.htm&language=en_US